# Signed Hexadecimal to decimal in Java

Tags: java, math, hex

I was wondering if it's possible to convert a signed Hexadecimal (negative) to its corresponding decimal value.

Comment: Assuming your input is a String starting in '-' and containing only hex digits, `Integer.parseInt(input,16)` will work.

Comment: show us what you have so far

Comment: What I am doing right now is that I take the negative hex and convert it to binary. I have a 2's compliment binary to decimal. It does work on small values. But when I try to convert large values like -4000(assuming hex) it is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have a hexadecimal value in form of a `String`.

The method [parseInt(String s, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) can take a hexadecimal (signed) String and with the proper radix (16) it will parse it  to an Integer.

```
int decimalInt = parseInt(hexaStr, 16);
```

---

the solution above only works if you have numbers like -FFAA07BB... if you want the Two's complements you'll have to convert it yourself.

```
String hex = "F0BDC0";

// First convert the Hex-number into a binary number:
String bin = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16), 2);

// Now create the complement (make 1's to 0's and vice versa)
String binCompl = bin.replace('0', 'X').replace('1', '0').replace('X', '1');

// Now parse it back to an integer, add 1 and make it negative:
int result = (Integer.parseInt(binCompl, 2) + 1) * -1;
```

or if you feel like having a one-liner:

```
int result = (Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("F0BDC0", 16), 2).replace('0', 'X').replace('1', '0').replace('X', '1'), 2) + 1) * -1;
```

---

If the numbers get so big (or small), that an Integer will have an overflow, use `Long.toString(...)` and `Long.parseLong(...)` instead.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately, it returns an unsigned integer(15777216). My hex value is "F0BDC0" which should be -1000000.

Comment: @Jujumancer I've edited my post... that self-made solution should work for you... But be careful this solution treats every number as a negative number, even if it would be positive! You'll have to determine whether the number is negative by yourself and either use the upper or the lower solution

Comment: Thank you. I''ll check it out with other values as well. I'll be using your method just for signed hex values. Cheers